# System.out.print(" "); syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token

Tags: java

I'm getting this error on this piece of code and I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
public class enc {
    //The Look-Up Table with the position of all the available characters
    public static final String LUT="*, .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input the sentence you want to encode.");
    String s= sc.nextLine();        
}
```

Comment: For the close voter, this is a reproducible and is not a "simple" typing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the code inside a method:

```
public class enc {
    //The Look-Up Table with the position of all the available characters
    public static final String LUT="*, .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input the sentence you want to encode.");
        String s= sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input the sentence you want to encode.");
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

should be in a code block such as a method rather than the class block

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public class enc {
    //The Look-Up Table with the position of all the available characters
    public static final String LUT="*, .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static void main (String args[]) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input the sentence you want to encode.");
   String s= sc.nextLine();        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lines:

```
System.out.print("Input the sentence you want to encode.");
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

Must be inside a method or a system initialiser block. Actually these are function calls which do not return anything. So cannot be in the class directly.

```
// In a method  
public class enc {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Input the sentence you want to encode.");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
// In a system initializer block
public class Test {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    {
        System.out.println("yoyo");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Actually those methods can be called directly in a class which actually return something. And must also be initialised to a variable of the respective type.